# How to insert the image on right top corner of panel header using flex?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, image, air

Anybody help me

How to insert the image on right top corner of panel using flex or action script .
i used

-`<mx:Panel x="38.5" y="28" titleIcon="@Embed('image/logo.png')"  id="register" width="375" height="534" layout="absolute" title="Registration Form  ">`

titleIcon attributs but not use . so how to insert ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question. Maybe you could post a sample of the code that works properly, and the code that doesn't?

Comment: is it ok now . could u know tell me

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to subclass the Panel and add your button(s) in the createChildren() method:

```
protected override function createChildren():void
{
     super.createChildren();

     mybtn = new Button();
     mybtn.label = "I am a button";
     mybtn.visible = true;
     mybtn.includeInLayout = true;
     mybtn.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, buttonClickHandler );
     rawChildren.addChild( mybtn );
}
```

To make your extended panel more useful, add styles for the buttons and use getStyle() to get the icons to use.

Comment: Did it work? In that case, an upvote and an accepted answer would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to display the image in the panel header or within the body of the panel itself?